# nginx static file cache using wrong path

Tags: nginx

In the .conf of a website I'm trying to get the static file caching to work.

Currently have the configuration for caching this:

```
location ~ \.(?:jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|ttf|woff|map)$ {
   expires 3d;
}
```

When I run the website it can't find any of those images because it's looking in `/etc/nginx/html/css/` or `/etc/nginx/html/img/`, etc.

This is not the correct path, just above this in the `location / {...}` part I set the path to root `/websites/keyboardmastery/html;`. Any idea why it keeps looking in `/etc/nginx/*` for the files as opposed to the root path?

Comment: Welcome to SF! Most nginx questions require the applicable `server` block (or blocks) be posted in order to receive a complete solution.

Comment: `just above this in the location / {...} part ` - why are you describing your config instead of just showing it? Much less ambiguous to see it.

Comment: masegaloeh - Thank you, that fixed it! First time using nginx.

Answer (score 2):

Put `root` directive inside location blocks wasn't good practices because you must adding `root` directive inside every location blocks. If nginx doesn't find `root` directive in location block or in server block, it will do fallback action by setting `root` directory to [--prefix path](http://nginx.org/en/docs/configure.html) when you compiled it.

Snippet from [nginx Pitfall](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#Root_inside_Location_Block)

> This works. Putting `root` inside of a location block will work and it's perfectly valid. What's wrong is when you start adding location blocks. If you add a `root` to every location block then a location block that isn't matched will have no root.

The solution is move `root` directive outside location blocks. You may set the `root` directive for specified location to override `root` directive value.

```
server {
    ...
    root /my/path;

    location / {
        ...
    }

    location /img {
        ...
    }
```

}